# What can cause an application to fail to get a connection from the pool, other than the total number of concurrent connections?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm seeing the following error:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Going by the figures from netstat, my machine has a total of 7 active connections (3 of which are from SQL Server Management Studio) but this instance of the application is failing to make a connection.

We've audited all of our code to ensure each and every `SqlConnection` is in a `using` block, and starting a new instance of the same application on the same machine works (whilst the broken one remains broken).

What else can I look at to diagnose the cause of the problem? Could it just be some over zealous firewalling going on somewhere, or could it be something in our code?

Comment: Are you using a SqlDataReader?  SqlCommand?  If so, make sure those are also within using blocks.  Essentially, anything that implements IDisposable should probably be in a using block.

Comment: Can you run `sp_who` or `sp_who2` on the SQL Server? How many rows are returned?

Comment: @Jeff Yep, everything has been code reviewed, and `using` everywhere - if the connection pool really was exhausted, I'd expect perfomon/netstat to show more active connections.